# Find the Greatest Common Factor of $x^4-px^3+(q-1)x^2+px-q$ $\\$ and $\\$ $x^4-qx^3+(p-1)x^2+qx-p$.

Tags: algebra-precalculus, polynomials

Find the Greatest Common Factor of $x^4-px^3+(q-1)x^2+px-q$ $\\$ and $\\$ $x^4-qx^3+(p-1)x^2+qx-p$.

$$
\begin{array}{c|l}
x^4-px^3+(q-1)x^2+px-q & x^4-qx^3+(p-1)x^2+qx-p \\
 & - \\
& x^4-px^3+(q-1)x^2+px-q \\
\hline  \\
& (p-q)x^3+(p-1-q+1)x^2+(q-p)x+(q-p)
\end{array}
$$

$\Rightarrow (p-q)x^3+(p-q)x^2-(p-q)x-(p-q) \\ \Rightarrow (p-q)(x^3+x^2-x-1) \\ \Rightarrow (p-q)[x^3-1^3+x(x-1)] \\ \Rightarrow (p-q)[(x-1)(x^2+x+1)+x(x-1)] \\  \Rightarrow (p-q)(x-1)(x+1)(x+1)$

So it seems like by inspection $(p-q)$ is not the G.C.F. because it isn't a divisor of $x^4$, thus it can be excluded from consideration. That leaves $(x-1), (x+1), (x+1)^2,(x^2-1),(x^3+x^2-x-1)$ as the potential G.C.F. Is there a quicker way to determine which (more than one perhaps?) is the G.C.F. besides tediously dividing the two polynomials at the top by each one? Thanks.

Comment: You can rewrite the first one as $$x^2(x^2-1)-px(x^2-1)+q(x^2-1)=(x^2-px+q)(x^2-1)$$ and similarly for the second with $p,q$ swapped.

Comment: @ThomasAndrews This was already in the answer below

Comment: Both polynomials have $\pm 1$ as obvious roots, so they are divisible by $(x-1)(x+1)=x^2-1$.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Notice that \begin{align}x^4-px^3+(q-1)x^2+px-q =& (x^4+(q-1)x^2-q) -px(x^2-1)\\
=& x^4 - x^2 +q(x^2-1) -px(x^2-1)\\
=&(x^2-1)(x^2-px+q)\end{align} and similary $$x^4-qx^3+(p-1)x^2+qx-p = (x^2-1)(x^2-qx+p)$$

So you need to find $\gcd(x^2-px+q, x^2-qx+p)$.

Comment: How do you break it down this way? Is there a formula?